# Не правильно работает,как исправить?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте,столкнулся с такой проблемой. Хочу подсвечивать активные вкладки,но когда добавлю index, ticket то перестаёт работать правильно

Нормально работает;

```
$class = 'navigation__sub';
if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'tickets.php') $class = 'navigation__sub navigation__sub--active navigation__sub--toggled';
```

А если сделать уже

```
$class = 'navigation__sub'; if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'tickets.php' || 'index.php') $class = 'navigation__sub navigation__sub--active navigation__sub--toggled';
```

то начинают всё вкладки светиться когда переходишь на какую либо вкладку,как это можно исправить?

Вывод класса $active;

Comment: if (basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'tickets.php' || basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ==  'index.php')

Comment: Выражение `'index.php'` всегда будет `true`. Используйте условия правильно. Правильный вариант вашего условия привёл предыдущий комментатор.

Comment: так тоже не работает,я уже так пробовал

Comment: @NexFive, данный вариант правильный и он точно работает, если, конечно, у вас нет ошибок где-то ещё.

Comment: @Pyramidhead, к сожалению не работает,две вкладки светятся. А должна светится та на которой я сейчас нахожусь

Comment: @NexFive, это значит только одно - у вас ошибки где-то ещё. Либо ошибки в коде, либо в логике.